# Complete newbie question, textview handle not recognizing

Tags: java, android, eclipse

My previous coding experience has been with python, and only scripts related to data stream processing.

I'm getting a compile error when referencing a textview handle

To boil some code down:
during onCreate(), calls a function setupHandles()

```
public void setupHandles(){
    //initialize internal controls to text labels
     TextView tvmoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moneyText);
     TextView tvsave = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.savingsText);
     ..... etc etc many more handles
```

now in a part of code from onResume(), I try to do, for example:

```
tvmoney.setText(("Money: $" + "foo" + "bar"));
```

Its saying that the tvmoney can't be resolved.  Why is this?  The setupHandles has to have run, onCreate, and it is public...   But if I put the line 3 in onResume, the handle works.  How can I get it to either pass the handles along, or make it truly public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference named tvmoney is obtained and only available in method `setupHandles()`. Once the execution of setupHandles() finishes, tvmoney is gone.

To solve this, just set tvmoney as a **global variable** (outside of any method)

Comment: I thought that was what the "public" part of setupHandles did  :(  It won't accept a line like `public TextView tvmoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.moneyText); ` either.

Comment: Ohh.  I see now.  Within the class, but outside any methods/functions.   Thank you very much, shihpeng.  Java is a world of difference from python!